# Used to call this "push it on the Accumulator."

Tags: javascript, push, accumulator

How do I? I want to save a URL for later. I have two different pages that go to a URL called page1.htm. I want to save the URL from the page that I came from to reach page1.htm. Before I retrieve the URL from page1.htm I may go to, say, 6 URLs before getting back to page1.htm. How would I retrieve the URL from page1.htm so I can go back to the page I originally came from to reach page1.htm? Is this possible in javascript? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The url from page1.htm is page1.htm. You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I actually want to go back to the page before page1.htm. I have about 3 pages that go to page1.htm. I need to determine which one I go back to from page1.htm. From page 1.htm I'll go to multiple pages and eventually come back to page1.htm. I need to determine which page called page1.htm. Hope I'm clear. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I could open a new page in the exact same location as page1.htm. Go through my pages and when wanting to go back to page1.htm I could trigger a history.back() from the newly opened pages to page1.htm.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited my original question and hope it is clear now.